# (How) does LM386 allow an input past its negative rail?

Tags: lm386

I am confused by the LM386. In the data sheet, multiple examples connect the inverting input directly to ground.

[image: simple LM386 circuit]

To me, that feels weird. How can the IC amplify if the input goes below GND?

The data sheet goes on: when left unconnected (or AC coupled) either input will float to 12.5 mV. That is certainly not enough to allow for the full 2Vrms output (500 mW into 8 Ohms) at a gain of 20.

Does the LM386 actually allow the input to go past the lower rail? How does it do that? Are the input transistor pairs all in saturation, i.e. \$V_C>V_B\$ ?

[image: LM386 equivalent circuit]

Comment: Vbe is the answer : with the input pin at 0, the input stage emitter is at +Vbe or about +0.6V. That's just enough +ve bias for all the rest to work. By -0.4V, the input transistor starts to saturate producing unacceptable distortion; hence the input specification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *Section 6.3 in the data sheet says that an acceptable input voltage is
> +/- 0.4 V. That is just below a single diode drop, so it would confirm your theory.*

[image]

Yes, that confirms what I thought about the PNP BJT input stage. It will sail close to BJT saturation with an instantaneous value at -0.4 volts but, it'll still work: -

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, the input signal falls below 0 volts quite significantly (-200 mV) without any problem or distortion in the output waveform (connected to an 8 Ω load). Signal is 1 kHz and transistor models are BC557 (PNP) and BC547 (NPN). Current source is 5 mA.

> *Simple answers are the best*

```
Simple answers are usually the best but, not at the expense of truth.
```

Answer (score 10):

*Note: This answer and the one by Andy aka were posted independently and within minutes of each other. The content is virtually identical. I appreciate Andy's effort, so I accepted his answer.*

---

With Andy aka confirming my suspicion that the input is indeed allowed to go negative, I rigged up the equivalent circuit in LTspice.

[image: LTspice scmeatic]

[image: trace]

For a supply voltage of 18V, the circuit deals with an 0.3Vp input with remarkably little distortion (50dB). Increasing the input further, the output starts to be clipped by the supply rails.

I will need to do some more digging to actually fully grok this circuit.

Q5 is an emitter follower, that is in saturation whenever the input goes negative. It still feeds a current waveform into Q6 that accurately tracks the input. Q6 has its collector pinned to 0.7V by Q10, so Q6 is in saturation almost all the time.

Comment: You are a gentleman for doing so. Appreciated.

Comment: and both are scholars of Analog Electronics

Answer (score 4):

When differential inputs are PNP the device may sense just below 0V=Vee.

When Ib=250nA (LM386) use Vbe=500mV ( for any BJT at 25’C) then when Vb=Vin=-0.2V (max in spec) Ve = 300mV which is reduced hFE but NOT “saturated” since Vc=0.

“Saturation” is when hFE is about < 20% of hFE or derated to 10% at rated Ic(sat) , Vce(sat) { or Ic/Ib=10 !} here Vce(sat) would be Vce(sat)<<100 mV (more like <50mV) so Vce=3xx mV at this low Ic is **not** saturated.

So the **simple explanation** is  iff the output is in the linear range to pull up the input PNP emitter with Vce=300 mV when Vbe=500mV and Vb(in)=-200 mV, you can use the base input below Vee!

Comment: The Ocham’s Razor